# Unable to launch application by using start_test_server_in_background

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, calabash

I have tried to open my application using start_test_server_in_background. I can see the iPhone simulator but my application is not opening in the simulator. It's showing the following error message.

[image]

Note: I have set APP_BUNDLE_PATH.

Any suggestions?

Comment: We need more details. Please see this calabash-ios topic - http://goo.gl/yQi0bE - and update your question.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The issue has been resolved after I reinstalled the provisioning profile.